# Tkinter Listbox: programmatically selecting Listbox item disables up/down cursor keys

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

The following code creates a standard listbox in tkinter. In normal use, after the user makes the first listbox selection with a mouse click, subsequent selections can be made either by clicking again with the mouse, or by using the up/down cursor keys. Both of these (mouse click and cursor keys) correctly trigger ListboxSelect and change the value of SelectedIndex using the associated function UserClickedSelection(event).

The code also includes a function that allows me to set a listbox selection programmatically. This works perfectly, and correctly changes SelectedIndex using the SetSelection(index) function. But...and this is the problem...after making a selection programmatically, the up/down arrow keys no longer function. The user needs to make the next selection using the mouse, and then the up/down arrow keys once again function normally.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

SelectedIndex = 0

def UserClickedSelection(event): # get user selection
    global SelectedIndex
    SelectedIndex = mylistbox.curselection()[0]

def SetSelection(index): # set selection
    global SelectedIndex
    mylistbox.selection_clear(0,tk.END)
    mylistbox.selection_set(index)
    mylistbox.activate(index)
    SelectedIndex = mylistbox.curselection()[0]
    
mylistbox = tk.Listbox(root,activestyle="none")
mylistbox.place(x=0,y=0)
mylistbox.config(selectmode=tk.BROWSE)
mylistbox.config(exportselection=False)
mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',UserClickedSelection)

mylist = ['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five']
mylistbox.insert(0,*mylist)

# Using function: set selection to index 2
SetSelection(2)

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, in the code I've used the programmatic function to select index 2 of the listbox. This works fine, but the up/down arrow keys do not work until another selection is made afterwards using a mouse click. So there is clearly a difference between a "real" user selection and my "programmatic" selection. Is there some way to rectify this? I need the up/down arrow keys to work consistently. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you just need to make sure the listbox has focus.

```
def SetSelection(index): # set selection
    ...
    mylistbox.focus_set()
```

Comment: @fmex: odd. They work fine for me. The code in your question already has the call to `activate`.

Comment: Yes, my error. The 'activate' line was included in the above code, but I had commented it out in my code editor. So, long story short, you are absolutely correct - the addition of that one line did entirely correct the problem. Many thanks!